# Enable mouse while typing

Tags: windows-8, drivers, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I know it's a frequently asked question, but I don't manage to find a solution.

I have a new Asus laptop (Asus S551LB-CJ003H) on Windows 8.1, and a Logitech Mouse M125. The problem is : when I type on my keyboard, the mouse left click is disabled. And, worse, it still lasts one second after the end of typing.

I have tried to go to Mouse and Keyboard properties in the Control panel, but I didn't find the option to disable this behavior. My mouse driver is up to date. And I haven't the possibility to downgrade it.

Finally, the problem also occurs for my touchpad. (but this is less annoying)

Comment: Check your touchpad control panel. It's probably a poorly implemented feature that's meant to prevent accidental clicks while typing.

Comment: Specifically asking, are you referring to the movement of your cursor, or clicking with it - or both?

Comment: @Thor just the click

Answer (score 1):

As said here : [Using keyboard disables touchpad left button for a second on Acer laptop in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/658095/using-keyboard-disables-touchpad-left-button-for-a-second-on-acer-laptop-in-wind)

> Go to the below registry value:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad
>
> And change "AAPThreshold" from 2 (or whatever setting it's at) to 0.
>
> You may have to reboot for it to take effect.

It has worked for me.