# How do I use a laptop tuchpad and press a key at the same time

Tags: laptop, keyboard, mouse, gaming

Recently, I lost my usb for my wireless mouse, so I deiced to use my tuchpad for gaming, unfortunatly, I learned that I cant press my "W" key while moving my tuchpad, this makes it very hard to get kills or do things in general. I have a lenovo laptop.

Comment: Are you saying that the 'W' (and only the 'W' key) doesn't respond while you have your other hand on the touchpad?

Comment: im sayiny my mouse stops moving when holding w

Comment: This seems to be a common issue with touchpads. You'll likely need to alter the touchpad settings to disable this, but the exact steps depend on who made the touchpad (Synaptics, ELANTech, etc.). If you want a specific answer, please consider [edit]ing the question with the touchpad manufacturer or model of laptop. Otherwise, here is a basic [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/399341/touchpad-does-not-respond-when-i-am-holding-key-on-the-keyboard) and a general Google search for ["cannot press w with touchpad"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cannot+press+w+with+touchpad).